# MATLAB - Find contour of a binary bit map?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matrix

I have a `10x10` binary bit map as follows. I am looking for an **efficient** way of finding its contour in MATLAB. (I have tried letting every value "look around" its neighbors' values and decide, but it is too inefficient. I expect the algorithm to scale up.)

```
false   false   false   false   false   false   false   false   false   false
false   false   true    true    true    true    true    true    false   false
false   true    true    true    true    true    true    true    true    false
false   true    true    true    true    true    true    true    true    false
false   true    true    true    true    true    true    true    true    false
false   true    true    true    true    true    true    true    true    false
false   true    true    true    true    true    true    true    true    false
false   true    true    true    true    true    true    true    true    false
false   false   true    true    true    true    true    true    false   false
false   false   false   false   false   false   false   false   false   false
```

Let's assume each boolean value resembles a square, and the left-bottom one sits over `x: 0-1; y: 0-1`. The output should be the points that form the boundary. You may assume the inner `true` block is alway convex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is dead simple.  Use the `bwperim` command in MATLAB, assuming you have the image processing toolbox.

You can call the function like so:

```
out = bwperim(A);  %//or
out = bwperim(A,conn);
```

The first way assumes that the pixel connectivity is a 4-pixel neighbourhood.  This will only look at the north, south, east and west directions.

If you specify an additional parameter called `conn` which is a single number, you can override this behaviour and specify the kind of behaviour you want when looking at neighbouring pixels.  For example, if `conn=8`, you would look at 8-pixel neighbourhoods for 2D (so N, NE, E, SE, S, SW, W, NW), or you can go into 3D if you have a 3D binary image... but for now, I'm assuming it's just 2D.  For the best accuracy, use 8.

As such, we have:

```
A = [false   false   false   false   false   false   false   false   false   false
false   false   true    true    true    true    true    true    false   false
false   true    true    true    true    true    true    true    true    false
false   true    true    true    true    true    true    true    true    false
false   true    true    true    true    true    true    true    true    false
false   true    true    true    true    true    true    true    true    false
false   true    true    true    true    true    true    true    true    false
false   true    true    true    true    true    true    true    true    false
false   false   true    true    true    true    true    true    false   false
false   false   false   false   false   false   false   false   false   false];

out = bwperim(A,8);
```

And it looks like:

```
out =

 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     0     0
 0     1     1     0     0     0     0     1     1     0
 0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0
 0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0
 0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0
 0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0
 0     1     1     0     0     0     0     1     1     0
 0     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

MATLAB outputs 1 for true and 0 for false.

As a bonus, this is what the shapes look like side by side:

[image]

## Edit from the comments

Going with your comments, you wish to find the set of points that make the perimeter.  As such, you can simply use the `find` command to do that for you.

```
[X,Y] = find(out == 1);
coords = [X Y];
```

What the `find` command does is that it searches your array and finds locations in the array that match the Boolean expression given in the parameter of `find`.  In this case, we wish to find **all** co-ordinates that have a pixel in `out` equal to 1, and `out` is our perimeter image.  As such, this effectively finds all pixels that are perimeter pixels.

We thus get:

```
coords =

  3     2
  4     2
  5     2
  6     2
  7     2
  8     2
  2     3
  3     3
  8     3
  9     3
  2     4
  9     4
  2     5
  9     5
  2     6
  9     6
  2     7
  9     7
  2     8
  3     8
  8     8
  9     8
  3     9
  4     9
  5     9
  6     9
  7     9
  8     9
```

`X` are the row co-ordinates, while `Y` are the column co-ordinates.  I've placed `X` and `Y` into a single 2D array for better presentation, but you can take the `X` and `Y` variables by themselves for further processing.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot man! My ultimate goal is actually to get a series of points that form the boundary. It seems still a bit tricky to go from here to that goal

Comment: @FarticlePilter That's also very easy.  Simply do `[X,Y] = find(out == 1);`  I've also edited my post to reflect your comments.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Almost done. Now the problem is I need to get the line boundary instead of the square boundary. Directly taking from `[X,Y] = find(out == 1)` gives me a "smaller" boundary like this http://i.stack.imgur.com/j5rwN.png But I need the boundary line as in http://i.stack.imgur.com/5u40a.png Thank you so much!

Comment: @FarticlePilter: I didn't quite follow what you meant.  Do you want to find the co-ordinates of a square that **fully** encapsulates that object (a.k.a. the minimum spanning bounding box)?  The second image is simply the original image that you showed us before

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion caused. I need to get the coordinates of the red dots as shown here http://i.stack.imgur.com/0ydIe.png But now I have these http://i.stack.imgur.com/j5rwN.png

Comment: The `find` command essentially gives you the co-ordinates at those red dots.... which is why I'm confused further

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55211/discussion-between-farticle-pilter-and-rayryeng).

Answer (score 2):

Here's another option:

```
B = bwboundaries(A)
```

this will get the x-y coordinates of any boundary. see more info [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwboundaries.html)...

Comment: This is a good one too.  It finds **all** of the perimeters of the objects in an image.  Nice one!

Answer (score 2):

Another option with image processing toolbox:

```
B = A - imerode(A,SE);
```

where `SE` is one of the kernels:

```
0 1 0    1 1 1
1 1 1    1 1 1
0 1 0    1 1 1
```

depending on which connectivity you want to use: first one for 8-connectivity, second one for 4-connectivity. For the difference between the two, recall that 8-connectivity allows diagonal neighbours.

With the image B, you can find all the points of the perimeters with the same technique displayed in another answer:

```
[Xp,Yp] = find(B);
```