# How to get the boundary edge for object in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I'm working to classify objects as human or non-human. My research focuses on the shape detection. I  tried to use the function `edge` in MATLAB but I do not know how to find the boundary edge for the head, neck and shoulders only for a human object from an image. In another words I want to ignore the internal edges; I just want the boundary edge.

Can anyone help me in this?
[i want to get this part only from the human object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fdmE.jpg)

Comment: i use MATLAB 2013 and i have not the image processing tools to use the boundary = bwperim(a2);

Comment: The third question linked has a solution that does not require the Image Processing Toolbox: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24075582/1377097